# Css border covering issue

Tags: html, css, border

I have this css in my page

```
li
{
    border-right:8px solid #101212;
    border-bottom:8px solid #33B5E5;
}
```

After that by default borders are displayed in this way.

[image]

But in my case I want something like this (bottom line covered black one)

[image]

How can I achieve this without changing my html (because it's generating automatically).

**Edit:**

Also note, that my ul tag is multiline, so everything isn't in one line and I can't have a workaround with giving border-bottom to my ul tag.

I have this in my css.

```
ul
{
   width:270px;
}

li
{
   float: left;
   width:90px;
}
```

and in my html

```
<ul>
            <li><a href="listview/index.html"><div class="menu_item_img">&#xe0dc;</div>Editing </a></li>
            <li><a href="listview/detailbuttons.html"><div class="menu_item_img">&#xe0db;</div>Editing </a></li>
            <li><a href="listview/databinding.html"><div class="menu_item_img">&#xe0da;</div>Editing</a></li>
            <li><a href="listview/pull-to-refresh.html"><div class="menu_item_img">&#xe0de;</div>Editing</a></li>
            <li><a href="listview/endless-scrolling.html"><div class="menu_item_img">&#xe0df;</div>Editing</a></li>
            <li><a href="listview/pull-with-endless.html"><div class="menu_item_img">&#xe0cc;</div>Editing</a></li>
            <li><a href="listview/press-to-load-more.html"><div class="menu_item_img">&#xe0cd;</div>Editing</a></li>
            <li><a href="listview/fixedheaders.html"><div class="menu_item_img">&#xe0ca;</div>Editing</a></li>
            <li><a href="listview/templates.html"><div class="menu_item_img">&#xe0c9;</div>Editing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your question is not clear for me, are you looking for that right border overlap the bottom border ? like the 2nd image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**css**

```
ul:before{
    border-bottom:solid 5px yellow; 
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
ul li{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    border-right:solid 5px green;
    height:100px;
}
```

[jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qug5/2/)

Comment: In my situation I can't do in this way, because my ul has three rows not only one.

Comment: I want bottom line under each row.

Comment: I have update my answer, please check this meet your requirement or not

Comment: I have multilne ul like this http://jsfiddle.net/3Qug5/3/.
Can you change your solution for multilne ul?

Comment: Update your answer with this one, this might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried it. I solved this issues.
You try this.

[See the output](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qug5/1/)

```
ul{
    border-bottom:solid 5px #33B5E5;
    height:50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    border-right:solid 5px #101212;
    height:100px;
    padding:0 10px;
   line-height:50px;
    z-index:-1;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: My question is about mulitline ul's

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle to match mine http://jsfiddle.net/3Qug5/3/ . In my case, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Looks nice, but also changes html... It will be good to achieve that effect inside one ul.